# Unable to get desired result from react slick

Tags: css, reactjs, components, slick.js, react-slick

I was trying to implement [React slick's](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started) multiple items carousel. The desired result is given below
[image]
but I want the center element to pop out a little just like

[image]

But I'm able to get this far

[image]

I want only three elements visible at a time and center element to be popped out. Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import Slider from "react-slick";
import DemoGuy from './DemoGuyMentors.png';
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export class Stories extends Component {
 render() {
    
  const settings = {
    className: "center",
    centerMode: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayspeed:1000
  };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="SliderWrapper">
                <Slider {...settings}>
                <div className="AchiversDetails">
                    <div className="MentorsPicAndLogoWrapper">
                        <img className="MentorImg" src={DemoGuy}></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="MentorsDetailsWordWrapper">
                            <h3>Lorem ipppsum</h3>
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum 
                        pellentesque metus ligula, ac elementum 
                        velit mollis in. Praesent ut dictum diam. Vivamus gravida eros at nunc 
                        vehicula pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                        Nulla suscipit bibendum quam quis pharetra. Aliquam odio leo, molestie eu 
                          luctus fringilla, suscipit at ipsum.
                        </p>
                    </div>   
                </div>

                <div className="AchiversDetails">
                    <div className="MentorsPicAndLogoWrapper">
                        <img className="MentorImg" src={DemoGuy}></img>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="MentorsDetailsWordWrapper">
                        <h3>LOREM IPPSUM</h3>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum 
                        pellentesque metus ligula, ac elementum 
                        velit mollis in. Praesent ut dictum diam. Vivamus gravida eros at nunc 
                        vehicula pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                        Nulla suscipit bibendum quam quis pharetra. Aliquam odio leo, molestie eu 
                        luctus fringilla, suscipit at ipsum.
                        </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div className="AchiversDetails">
                    <div className="MentorsPicAndLogoWrapper">
                        <img className="MentorImg" src={DemoGuy}></img>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div className="MentorsDetailsWordWrapper">
                            <h3>Lorem ipppsum</h3>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                                Vestibulum pellentesque metus ligula, ac elementum 
                                velit mollis in. Praesent ut dictum diam. Vivamus gravida eros at 
                                nunc vehicula pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                                Nulla suscipit bibendum quam quis pharetra. Aliquam odio leo, 
                               molestie eu luctus fringilla, suscipit at ipsum.
                            </p>
                    </div>   
                </div>

                <div className="AchiversDetails">
                    <div className="MentorsPicAndLogoWrapper">
                        <img className="MentorImg" src={DemoGuy}></img>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div className="MentorsDetailsWordWrapper">
                        <h3>LOREM IPPSUM</h3>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum 
                            pellentesque metus ligula, ac elementum 
                            velit mollis in. Praesent ut dictum diam. Vivamus gravida eros at 
                            nunc vehicula pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                            Nulla suscipit bibendum quam quis pharetra. Aliquam odio leo, 
                           molestie eu luctus fringilla, suscipit at ipsum.
                        </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div className="AchiversDetails">
                    <div className="MentorsPicAndLogoWrapper">
                        <img className="MentorImg" src={DemoGuy}></img>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div className="MentorsDetailsWordWrapper">
                        <h3>LOREM IPPSUM</h3>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum 
                        pellentesque metus ligula, ac elementum 
                        velit mollis in. Praesent ut dictum diam. Vivamus gravida eros at nunc 
                        vehicula pulvinar. Aliquam erat volutpat. 
                        Nulla suscipit bibendum quam quis pharetra. Aliquam odio leo, molestie eu 
                            luctus fringilla, suscipit at ipsum.
                        </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                </Slider>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Stories
```

Note: When I change the slideToShow:3. Only two elements are entirely visible and a half on both sides.
Following is the CSS I have used

```
.AchiversDetails{
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 52px rgba(70, 74, 140, 0.24);
 padding: 3rem;
 border-radius: 2%;
}


.slick-slide {
  margin: 27px 27px;
}
.slick-list {
  margin: 0 -27px;
}
```

Rest of the classed doesn't hold any css properties.

The desired final output is
[image]

I can implement the css which is inside the box. But its the slider I'm unable to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`centerMode` does not work correctly unless you use an odd value for the `slidesToShow` setting. You should be able to tweak the padding between slides with the `centerPadding` option instead of your `slick-slide` and `slick-list` CSS.

```js
  const settings = {
    className: "center",
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    speed: 500,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayspeed:1000
  };
```

To get your center slide to be larger than the others, you can target it with CSS and scale it up:

```css
.slick-center .AchiversDetails {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: I have tried implementing what you said. The centerPadding does nothing. Also, It doesn't matter whether I'm using an odd or even slider when centerMode:true is enabled There are half cut sliders coming as shown in the 2nd and 3rd pics of question.

Comment: Are you setting widths on `AchiversDetails` or your slider?